# Best way to make a ggplot with three lines on the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use ggplot2 to make a plot for the following data:

```
 Response Type             Size       
      <dbl> <chr>            <chr>     
    12  SoilYieldMapping    0-600
    34  SoilYieldMapping    600-1,000
    39  SoilYieldMapping    1,000-1,300
    50  SoilYieldMapping    1,300-1,700
    54  SoilYieldMapping    1,700-2,200
    49  SoilYieldMapping    2,200-2,900
    67  SoilYieldMapping    2,900-3,800
    80  SoilYieldMapping    3,800+
    12  GuidanceSystem  0-600
    24  GuidanceSystem  600-1,000
    33  GuidanceSystem  1,000-1,300
    40  GuidanceSystem  1,300-1,700
    60  GuidanceSystem  1,700-2,200
    60  GuidanceSystem  2,200-2,900
    78  GuidanceSystem  2,900-3,800
    84  GuidanceSystem  3,800+
    12  VariableRateTechnology  0-600
    20  VariableRateTechnology  600-1,000
    18  VariableRateTechnology  1,000-1,300
    23  VariableRateTechnology  1,300-1,700
    32  VariableRateTechnology  1,700-2,200
    32  VariableRateTechnology  2,200-2,900
    29  VariableRateTechnology  2,900-3,800
    40  VariableRateTechnology  3,800+
```

I would like the 8 categories for farm size on the x axis, the response on the y axis, and a different colored line for each of the three types.

However, I get this error code when I try to plot it:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Here is my ggplot2 code:

```
plot <- ggplot(data=data,aes(x=Size,y=Response,color=(Type))) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_grey(base_size = 22) +
  ylim(0,100) +
  ggtitle("Percent Adoption of Precision Ag for Corn in the US") +
  ylab("Percent of Farms Who Use Each Technology") +
  xlab("Farm Size")
```

I thought that this would be straightforward, but it seems like I don't understand what's going on as well as I had hoped. Any advice would be a huge help. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want Response on the y-axis, I'd suggest you replace `y=Size` by `y = Response` inside your `aes()` statement.

Comment: That was just a typo, thanks for pointing it out. When I do this, the plot looks correct, but there is no data on it. I updated the error that it gives me. Each category of farm size should have one piece of data for each Type, and I would like this to form 3 lines as farm size increases. Any idea how I can make this happen?

Comment: try adding add `group = Type` to the `aes`

Comment: This solved it, thank you!